# How to Change Prev/Next Arrows pictures in Owl Carousel?

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

So instead of using the arrows owl has on their carousel I want to use an arrow I found. I set it as a background image but the arrows still remain grey and unchanged. Do I have to change something in the owl css? Also is there an easy way to make the arrows responsive by moving relative to the height of the page?

```
.icon-arrow-left {
    background-image: url("css/icon-arrow-left.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.icon-arrow-left:hover {
    background-image: url("css/images/icon-arrow-left.png");
}
.icon-arrow-right {
    background-image: url("css/images/icon-arrow-left.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.icon-arrow-right:hover {
    background-image: url("css/icon-arrow-left.png");
}
```

Comment: Are you using, old Owl-Carousel ?
as I've used `#SliderID .owl-prev { background: url(../images/prev-btn.png) no-repeat;  }` and its working perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm using the one from here http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/ I tried something like that but it is still just the same grey arrow.

Comment: the `class` you've used here is confusing me, as far as I know about `owl-carousel`, I've never use them.

Comment: Oh I used those classes because I created those classes in the navigation text in the javascript file. Other than that, I have it set so that once it reaches a certain screen size(tablet and mobile). How do I make it so that the arrows move based on the size? I am using position:relative right now.

Comment: If your main goal to just change the nav icons(prev&next) then for this you don't have to alter `owl-carousel` `JS` file, just use simple `CSS` and for devices use `media-query`, that'll be more enough.